# How the path should be when including images into MvCMailer Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

im trying to embed an image when sending an email with MvCMailer like this:

```
    Dictionary<string,string> resources = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    resources["logo"] = new Uri(new Uri(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))), "/Content/images/logo.png").ToString();
    mailSender.Confirm(user.Username, user.Email, link,resources).Send();
```

How ever it generate this:

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

Im not sure what kind of path i should send, and how to generate it ?

Stack Trace:

```
     at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, ContentType contentType)
   at Mvc.Mailer.LinkedResourceProvider.Get(String contentId, String filePath)
```

Comment: when you are sending the attachment.. is that from a local machine why not let MVCMailer use the relative path of the attachment.

Comment: you are using System.Net.Mail so outside of rights/permission issue to the fileShare looks like... you will also need to create an Attachment object..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resource paths should be local paths on disk, not URLs.

Write

```
resources["logo"] = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/logo.png");
```

Comment: but i was wondering how i make it as a background image instead of inline image ?

Comment: Using CSS, with a `cid:` URI.

Comment: im sorry i didnt quite get what is cid: URI can you please provide me a little example ?

Comment: `background-image: url('cid:logo')` http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1759/embedding-images-revisited/   Note that not all mail clients support background images.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add the code to do the attachment.. 
  if this is not a rights or permissions issue try this

```
public virtual MailMessage Welcome(string email, string name)
{     
   var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Welcome to MvcMailer"};
   mailMessage.To.Add(email);
   ViewBag.Name = name;
   PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Welcome");
   return mailMessage; 
}
```

Comment: I know was telling hime that he would have to add the code to embed the image .. we don't use MCVMailer on my current project..